# This method must return a result of type int?

Tags: java, return-value

Why does it say the method must return of type int? The returns are integers

```
public static int search(int[] nums)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What value do you want?");
    int value = keyboard.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
    {
        if(nums[i] == value)
            return nums[value];
        else
            return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if `i >= nums.length`?

Comment: Yes, but if the for loop is not executed, you return nothing. Furthermore the else in your for is not what you are looking for. Currently you will just check if the first number in the array is the value you search. Get rid of this else.

Comment: `nums[value]` is the wrong thing to return.  If the user says they want to search for 100, and 100 is in the array, what do you want to return?  The 100th element of `nums`?  Even if `nums` is only 8 elements long?  That can't work.

Answer (score 2):

if `nums` is empty, the for loop never gets executed, thus you return nothing

do this

```
public static int search(int[] nums)
{
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("What value do you want?");
  int value = keyboard.nextInt();
  for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
  {
    if(nums[i] == value)
    return nums[value];
    else 
    return -1;
 }
 return 0;   // default value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that returned type is known when loop is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

in case `nums[]` is empty array or null. (But null value makes a nullpointer exception `nums.length`.) In that case loop will not execute and it would be a void return so to avoid this situation you must declare a default return statement.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst your return types *inside* the loop are of type `int`, your loop isn't guaranteed to actually run, and you don't have a return value (and hence type) in the scenario that your loop *doesn't* run.

Answer (score -1):

Not all paths returns something.
You could avoid that kind of mistake by adding a return after the `for` loop, or by using a return variable. It also look like your trying to search the array for the number the user typed. If so, you don't want the else case, or it will only check for the first number in `nums`.

```
public static int search(int[] nums)
{
    int ret = -1;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What value do you want?");
    int value = keyboard.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
    {
       if(nums[i] == value)
       {
           ret = nums[value];
           break;
       }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to fix the program's logic, please do so correctly.